# Change ElementName from generate xsd class

Tags: c#, xsd

Using the xsd.exe tool, class are generate from a xsd file.
I would like to change the name of a root element put I can not since the XmlRootElementAttribute can not be duplicate. So idealy I would like that the xsd tool generate a partial classe like this:

```
...
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Request", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class SendMessage  { ... }
```

But I have no clue how to change the ElementName propertie.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take your XSD defines an element ***SendMessage***, and you want the annotation to be something else, ***Request*** in your case.

Short answer is no, it cannot be done with XSD.exe alone; the tool doesn't allow a syntax where one can customize the name of the generated classes.

Which brings in the long version of the answer... The annotations always reflect what the XML is. If you change the ElementName value, then your generated XML will be different. If you want the XML different, then you should change the schema file instead.

This is the kind of question that needs a lot of explaining as to **why** would one want this... in order to get a positive answer, as in "yes, this is how achieve the ***why***".

Comment: Why? Because in a legacy system I have some message that are distinguish by their namespace. For example I have `<request xmlns="http://SendMessage">...`, `<request xmlns="http://ReceiveMessage">...` and so on. This yield a conflict when class are generate.

Comment: xsd.exe has the ability to generate output in different namespaces; take a look at the command line options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the /namespace in particular. This way, the classes may have the same name,  but in different namespaces... et voila, pas des conflits... :)

Comment: That is a solution but it have several drawback, first you have to create a namespace for each of the Resquest, that is not really what C# namespace are for. Second I have to prefix all Request by their respective namespace and I will since I will be using them in the same class. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Well... namespaces are exactly for this kind of scenario where Table in furniture is not the same as Table in database. As for prefixing, there are ways around it; at the top of your file add `using SendRequest = Something.Request;` and `using Response = SomethingElse.Request;` ... that should deal with code readability...